# How to get rid of objects (coordinates) in one pandas database that are within 3 distance units of objects (coordinates) in another?

Tags: python, pandas, coordinates

I have two Pandas dataframes, each containing a collection of coordinates (x,y). One is much shorter than the other. I want to omit all the objects in the longer database that are within a certain distance of objects in the shorter database.

Basically I want to define a circle of diameter 3 around each point in the shorter database, and omit all points in the larger database that are within those circles. I first did this by using a for loop and making squares (side length 3) around each point, which approximately worked, but I do not know how to modify it so that it omits objects within a certain radius.

Here is the code I used for the squares that I am trying to fix.

L and B are (x,y) coordinates, LAT is the longer database, HE is the shorter one.

```py
for i in np.arange(0,HE.shape[0],1):
   NEW = LAT[ (LAT['B'] > (HE['B'].iloc[i] + 1.5) ) | (LAT['B'] < (HE['B'].iloc[i] - 1.5)) & (LAT['L'] > (HE['L'].iloc[i] + 1.5) ) | (LAT['L'] < (HE['L'].iloc[i] - 1.5))]
```

It works to cut out squares, but that is not what I need.